# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Tags: java

```
public class dereks {
public static void main (String [] args){
    int array [] = {1,2,3,5,6,7};
    int sum =0;
    for(int counter=0; counter<=array.length; counter++){
        sum+=array[counter];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this?? I can't understand why I'm getting the error message "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at dereks.main(dereks.java:7)" .

Comment: You have an off-by-one error. Try stepping through your code manually to see what the issue is.

Comment: Arrays are 0-based in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your for loop terminating condition from `<=` to `<`:

```
for(int counter=0; counter<array.length; counter++){
    sum+=array[counter];
}
```

Or more simply, use foreach syntax:

```
for(int i : array){
    sum+=i;
}
```

The foreach syntax is preferred when you don't actually need the index each element is at.

Comment: Excellent..the '=' sign was causing the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the error because your loop limit is `<=array.length`. The array elements are 0 through `array.length-1`.

Answer (score 3):

Array indices start from `0`. This means that the last element is at `array.length - 1`.

Use: `counter < array.length`